# ESCAPE not recognized in Spring JPA

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm getting tje exception when trying to start Spring Boot application:

> "antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: ESCAPE"

Code:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;


public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long> {

   @Query("SELECT e FROM Post e WHERE UPPER(e.title) LIKE UPPER(:filterValue ESCAPE '%') OR UPPER(e.content) LIKE UPPER(:filterValue ESCAPE '%') ORDER BY e.title ASC")
   Page<Post> findAllByTitleContainingIgnoreCaseOrContentContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByTitleAsc(@Param("filterValue") String filterValue, Pageable pageable);

}
```

I'm trying to implement the query in such a way as to be able to include the wildcard from the service layer. At this time, I replace all `*` with `%` and pass it to the data access layer.

Before I changed to the above, the sql output showed that the `%` was being escaped, and thus not matching any records.

The above is the effort to prevent the `%` character from being escaped in the query, but I get the error that `ESCAPE` is not recognised.

UPDATE: I think I misunderstood what the `ESCAPE` keyword does. If `Chi%` is passed into the original CrudRepository method, it escapes it so that the query uses `%Chi\%%` and I need it to use `%Chi%%`. I thought `ESCAPE` made the escaped `\%` unescaped. I believe that is incorrect. I'm back to trying to figure out how to use it to accept wildcard searches.

I'm leaving this question here so that anyone else who may not understand, might be able to glean some help from this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `ESCAPE` out of `UPPER` and enable native query using `nativeQuery = true`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Post e WHERE UPPER(e.title) " +
       "LIKE (UPPER(:filterValue) ESCAPE '%') OR UPPER(e.content) " +
       "LIKE (UPPER(:filterValue) ESCAPE '%') ORDER BY e.title ASC", nativeQuery = true)
Page<Post> findAllByTitleContainingIgnoreCaseOrContentContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByTitleAsc(
    @Param("filterValue") String filterValue, Pageable pageable);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Comment: Thank you. As far as I can tell, that doesn't make use of the Pageable parameter, which I also need. ( org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable )