# Using a wildcard with a Spring JPA / CrudRepository

Tags: sql, spring, jpa

I've tried different approaches and searched high and low and I have been unable to make this work.

The following is the Method signature in the CrudRepository that works just find as a filter.

```
Page<Post> findAllByTitleContainingIgnoreCaseOrContentContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByTitleAsc(String title, String content, Pageable pageable);
```

For example, if I search for the term `Chicken` it does exactly as it should and returns all Posts containing the word Chicken.
I am trying to get it to do a search like `Chicken*Potato` to search for any posts Chicken and Potato appear somewhere in the title or content. The front end sends the wild card as `*` and I have to change it to `%` in the backend, but the ways I've been trying to do that the `%` gets escaped in the actual sql that is run.

I get the impression there is no way to do it with the CrudRepository method signature approach, but is there a way to do it at all while using Spring JPA and the Pageable?

Comment: SQL uses `%` as a wildcard and not `*`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I know that. I updated the question to be more clear. I hadn't realized I'd missed pointing that out.

Comment: Where do you do the change from * to %? In the frontend or before executing this method? Judging from your modified question you do the first.

Comment: I change it in the service layer, then use it in the method above. Here is a related question I'd asked earlier in the day that may help explain the efforts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76086040/escape-not-recognized-in-spring-jpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can make exactly what I'm looking for with the CrudRepository. I needed something that would take multiple words with a `*` delimiter, that would be able to filter both the title and content and return only those records in which both words appeared. I ended up NOT using the CrudRepository. The solution I came up with is shown below:

The service layer splits the input on `*`,

```
...
searchTerms = filterValue.split("\\*");
result = this.dao.searchPosts(searchTerms, pageable);
...
```

And in the data access layer:

```
public Page<Post> searchPosts(String[] searchTerms, Pageable pageable) {
    String[] allConditions = new String[searchTerms.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < searchTerms.length; i++) {
        allConditions[i] = "LOWER(CONCAT(p.title, ' ', p.content)) LIKE LOWER(?" + (i + 1) + ")";
    }

    String query = "SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE 1=1";
    if (searchTerms.length > 0) {
        query += " AND " + String.join(" AND ", allConditions);
    }
    query += " ORDER BY p.title ASC";

    TypedQuery<Post> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, Post.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < searchTerms.length; i++) {
        typedQuery.setParameter(i + 1, "%" + searchTerms[i] + "%");
    }

    long totalCount = typedQuery.getResultList().size();

    typedQuery.setFirstResult(pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize());
    typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

    List<Post> posts = typedQuery.getResultList();
    return new PageImpl<>(posts, pageable, totalCount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> to search for ANY posts Chicken AND Potato appear somewhere in the
> title OR content

It is possible without SQL query. For the above search use this:

```
findByTitleContainsIgnoreCaseAndContentContainsIgnoreCaseOrTitleContainsIgnoreCaseAndContentContainsIgnoreCaseOrderByTitle
```

Please note: you will need to provide both filters twice as parameters. Like:

```
("chicken", "potato", "potato", "chicken")
```